# every product of complete metric space is Baire

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Here is the question:

> Prove that every product of complete metric space is Baire w.r.t the product space.

Totally no idea. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $I$ be an index set, and for $i\in I$ let $\langle X_i,d_i\rangle$ be a complete metric space. Let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, with the product topology. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n$ be dense open subset of $X$, and let $G=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$; we need to show that $G$ is dense in $X$. To that end let $V$ be a non-empty open set in $X$. Then there are a finite $F\subseteq I$ and open sets $V_i$ in $X_i$ for $i\in F$ such that

$$B\overset{\text{def}}=\prod_{i\in F}V_i\times\prod_{i\in I\setminus F}X_i\subseteq V\;,$$

and it suffices to show that $B\cap G\ne\varnothing$.

Let $X_F=\prod_{i\in F}X_i$. Now use the following facts:

- $X_F$ is completely metrizable.
- Without loss of generality we may assume that $U_n\supseteq U_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
- The projection map $\pi_F:X\to X_F$ is open, so $\pi_F[U_n]$ is open in $X_F$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.